# I am getting a Array Index out of bounds yet I can't find the what is causing it?

Tags: java

In this class I am just working with a binary file but every time I compile I get an array index out of bounds all I needed to do was enhance this code so instead of it reading and writing from a text file it does it using binary, my array list seems to be fine to me? any help would be appreciated

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;

public final class ProductBinaryFile implements ProductDAO
{
    private ArrayList<Product> products = null;
    private Path productsPath = null;
    private File productsFile = null;

    private final String FIELD_SEP = "\t";

    public ProductBinaryFile()
    {
        productsPath = Paths.get("products.bin");
        productsFile = productsPath.toFile();
        **products = this.getProducts();**
    }

    public ArrayList<Product> getProducts()
    {
        // if the products file has already been read, don't read it again
        if (products != null)
            return products;        

        products = new ArrayList<>();        

        if (Files.exists(productsPath))  // prevent the FileNotFoundException
        {
            try (DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(
                     new BufferedInputStream(
                     new FileInputStream(productsFile))))
            {
                // read all products stored in the file
                // into the array list
                String line = in.readUTF();
                while(line != null)
                {
                    String[] columns = line.split(FIELD_SEP);
                    String code = columns[0];
                    **String description = columns[1];**
                    String price = columns[2];

                    Product p = new Product(
                        code, description, Double.parseDouble(price));

                    products.add(p);

                    line = in.readUTF();                    
                }
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
                return null;
            }
        }
        return products;            
    }

    public Product getProduct(String code)
    {
        for (Product p : products)
        {
            if (p.getCode().equals(code))
                return p;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean addProduct(Product p)
    {
        products.add(p);
        return this.saveProducts();
    }

    public boolean deleteProduct(Product p)
    {
        products.remove(p);
        return this.saveProducts();
    }

    public boolean updateProduct(Product newProduct)
    {
        // get the old product and remove it
        Product oldProduct = this.getProduct(newProduct.getCode());
        int i = products.indexOf(oldProduct);
        products.remove(i);

        // add the updated product
        products.add(i, newProduct);

        return this.saveProducts();
    }

    private boolean saveProducts()
    {        
        try (DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(
                               new BufferedOutputStream(
                               new FileOutputStream(productsFile))))
        {

            // write all products in the array list
            // to the file
            for (Product p : products)
            {
                out.writeUTF(p.getCode() + FIELD_SEP);
                out.writeUTF(p.getDescription() + FIELD_SEP);
                out.writeDouble(p.getPrice());
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }   
}
```

my text file am trying to read from:
[image]

Comment: You need to tell us where it's happening, especially if we can't compile your example

Comment: And some sample input.

Comment: 1) You won't get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException from compiling. It is a run time exception. 2) getProducts() can throw an ArrayListOutOfBoundsException if a given line does not produce three or more columns. You don't handle this exceptional condition.

Comment: I can't input anything it just goes towards the exception when I click run it says the issue is in my getProducts method yet it seems fine to me??

Comment: Yes, that error you get where it says the issue is in your getProducts? copy all of the text and paste it into your question. Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Did you do what I suggested in my answer?  Also, if you're getting compile time errors, you need to post exactly what they are, or we won't be able to help you.

Comment: I've updated my answer again.  It contains all that we've discussed since the inception of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In below code, looks like your `columns` array length is 1. So, it can not access [1]. It can only access [0]

```
    String[] columns = line.split(FIELD_SEP);
    String code = columns[0];
    **String description = columns[1];**
```

Check the length of `columns` array, by doing system out:

```
System.out.println("columns length : " + columns.length)
```

**Answer Updated after Question updation:**

After your recent comment and new error point** to `this.getProducts`, I am assuming that your issue lies in `productFile` content.

**Do this:**

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(productsFile));
in.readLine();
```

The way you are reading it is not right. Do what I have suggested. Then do split after reading the line.

**Note:** `readUTF` is for reading characters which have been encoded using *formatted* UTF-8. This simply means that this reads the data in the form of java primitive types. So that when you read, you can convert them directly back to java primitive type. Not recommend for reading normal UTF-8 string.

**Note:** `readUTF` should only used when you have written in the form of java primitive types(**ie:** `writeUTF`). **Reading/Writing** in the form of java primitive types.

**Answer Updated (As OP wants to read it as java primitive types):**

The way you are reading and getting the result is perfectly fine. Because `readUTF` is supposed to read java primitive types. Which is why you are getting *java*(check text file) in `line` variable. Check the way you are writing it. I don't know why you are doing string split when you are directly reading java primitive types. You need to keep doing `readUTF` and create the `Product` object out of it.

Comment: It's only going to have a length of one if there are zero tabs.  If the input contains two tabs, for example: "gdfb\tdrfb\trdb," it will have length 3...right?

Comment: @SteveP., well, we don't know the input. We can only assume based on the error he is getting.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I advised him to get the length of columns/iterate through it and print the elements of the array (so that he would know what's actually in there).

Comment: @SteveP., Before doing iteration, he should do the array.length after split so that we know what is the array length exactly.

Comment: Sorry if I was ambiguous, that's what I meant.  In order to iterate through the array, he would need to know the length.  For his own edification, I imagine it would also be helpful to see exactly what's in there...

Comment: My column length surprisingly is 1, I dont get why though, I mean I have an array and I added three elements?

Comment: @babaysteps, Alright, so I was right. Now check updated answer after your recent comment and error point.

Comment: Look at my answer, you probably have zero tabs, so since you're splitting and using tab as a delimiter, you'll only get one element.

Comment: @SteveP., Yup, that is 1 of the possibilities.

Comment: It could be something else, but I assume that's the most likely cause.

Comment: @SteveP., Hmmm, after what he said about `this.getProducts`, I think his `Products` array may be null.

Comment: So how do I get my columns arraylist to access 3 elements because it only showing 1 as the column length?

Comment: @babaysteps, what is the value inside `columns[0]` ? Do system.out and let me know.

Comment: i should get "java book 19.00" My column[0] gives me java but columns[1] and columns[2] don't process

Comment: @babaysteps Ok, do `System.out.print(line)` and see what's inside. So we know what we are splitting here.

Comment: I get the same as columns[0], "java".

Comment: @babaysteps, Which means that is what you are reading from a file. Ok, I want to know the content of the `productFile`. Please post.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with `readUTF()`, but it seems that it's not reading in the entire string, only the first token.  If you simply have a file with standard text, why not use BufferedReader or Scanner?

Comment: am converting it to binary, readUTF reads and returns strings encoded with utf and buffer reader is when dealing with text file not binary

Comment: Even if you are going to convert it to binary, the text file that you posted is a standard text file that Scanner or BufferedReader can read from.

Comment: The whole point is to modify this class so it uses a binary file named products.bin

Comment: @babaysteps, readUTF is for reading characters which have been encoded using formatted UTF-8. aren't you reading this from a file ?

Comment: but I need to store the product code and description as UTF characters

Comment: @babaysteps, Alright, so you are storing it as java primitive types. So that you can read the bytes and convert them back to java primitive types. Is that correct ?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that your error is in one of the following lines:

```
String code = columns[0]; 
String description = columns[1]; 
String price = columns[2];
```

My theory is that what you're reading in is not as long as you think it is (perhaps tab is a poor choice for a delimiter); so you're only getting one entry or something.  Get the length of columns and iterate through it (and print the elements) to make sure it's exactly what you think it is.

EDIT: 
The way split works is that it takes your string and separates it based on your delimiter, in this case: tab.  It's only going to have a length of one if there are zero tabs. If the input contains two tabs, for example: "gdfb\tdrfb\trdb," it will have length 3

Second Edit:
If you're only reading a standard text file, why not use BufferedReader or Scanner?
Ex: `Scanner fromFile= new Scanner(new FileReader(filename));`
then you can just use `nextLine()` to get the entire line and split on that.

Comment: With respect to something going wrong in getProducts(), the only thing I can think of is you getting a NullPointerException because you're calling `p.getCode().equals(code)` on a NULL product or somehow, code is a NULL string.